# javascript global property definition

Tags: javascript

why is it possible to do this:

```
test: {

  one: 1;
  two: 2;
  three: 3;

}
```

and not possible to do this:

```
var test = {

  one: 1;
  two: 2;
  three: 3;

}
```

by default the properties are separated by comma, but in the first example it is working, in the second I get an error, the question is why the first one is working if that is a wrong JSON, hm?

Comment: in both of the examples you should be using commas, rather than semicolons -- check out this really basic tutorial on declaring objects in JavaScript -- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: @Rajesh Depends of the definition of "invalid". This is some useless code but it's valid from a technical point of view.

Comment: it is global defined thats why

Comment: @jogjog No that is not why.

Comment: but it is working

Comment: You are using a [labeled block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) with some labels you don't do anything with. It has nothing to do with the global scope. It is valid JavaScript but it doesn't do anything for you. It does **not** declare an object.

Comment: @Ivar the dot and comma togheter are wrong separators? but no errors still

Comment: @jogjog like I said, it is **valid** JavaScript. So you will not get any errors. The operators are fine, it just does not what you are expecting it does.

Comment: @Ivar also what is the purpose of this kind of things, why they exist?

Comment: @jogjog Denys linked in his answer to an article about labels. I suggest you read it.

Answer (score 4):

The first exemple isn't really "working". It's valid but does nothing.

You just have a block and a bunch of [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and useless statements.

If you want to define an object with properties, you *do* have to use commas.

Comment: but i get no errors from it, and it has no errors in the console

Comment: Yes, there's no error in the first code. It just does nothing because  `a:1;` is just a label followed by a statement.